# why windows server keep stopping startup services even it is automatic?

Tags: windows-server-2019, kaspersky

I have two servers, the first one is windows server 2016, and the second is windows server 2019 with Kaspersky security center 12 installed.
both servers won't start up the automatic startup services by itself, after restart or after a while of starting the services manually, it stops them.
I've tried to reinstall windows, SFC/scan, install all windows updates, change the startup to delayed, nothing works
[Windows Server 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f1jT.jpg)
[Windows Server 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfxtr.jpg)

I have windows server 2012, and the same Kaspersky security center is being installed ... and it works perfectly fine.

what do you suggest?

Comment: Where I have seen this, it is usually a function of the software that is stopping.  In Services, find the software, right click to see Properties. Now in the Recovery Tab, set First, Second and Subsequent (start) failures.  You would need to restart the software. I have done the for Quick Books for example.

Comment: Check the Windows event log, under the Application section. You should see the reason for the service stopping, it could be an exception causing it to fall over.

Comment: @John same issue , nothing has been changed